# Generating single hash of CSV file

Tags: django, python-3.x, csv, hash

I have a service that received CSV files with size ranging from MBs to GBs and I need to generate a **single hash** against all contents of a file.

Is there an optimized solution for this that doesn't require me to read the file line by line and concatenate each line in a string and then generate a hash of that string? That method would take too much time for a file that can contain millions of rows.

Any help will be appreciated. By the way, I will be using `SHA256` from `hashlib` for hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it with following code:

```
import hashlib
def generateHash(path):

    sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
    block_size=256*128

    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(block_size), b''):
            sha256.update(chunk)

    return sha256.hexdigest()
```